# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is isomorphic to $End(\mathbb{Z}_p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elliptic-curves, p-adic-number-theory

Here $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is p-adic integer. The isomorphism $End(\mathbb{Z}_p) \cong \mathbb{Z}_p $ appears on the Silverman's textbook "elliptic curve". It seems it can be proved using an action on $\mathbb{Z}/p^r \mathbb{Z}$ induced by endomorphism on $p^r\mathbb{Z}$ to itself. But I am not sure about details. So how to prove this?

Comment: $f(p^r\Bbb{Z}_p)= p^r f(\Bbb{Z}_p)\subset p^r\Bbb{Z}_p$ so any endomorphism is continuous and $f$ is determined by $f|_\Bbb{Z}$ ie. by $f(1)$.

Comment: @reuns Why we need to prove that endomorphism is continuous?

Comment: To ensure that $f$ is determined by $f|_\Bbb{Z}$ ie. by $f(1)$

Comment: You can avoid the word continuous by showing that $f$ is well-defined as endomorphism of $\Bbb{Z}_p/(p^r)$ then considering the projective limit of those reductions, each of them being given by an integer $\bmod p^r$, but overall it will be the same.